# How do I turn this code into a working function?

Tags: r, function, sentiment-analysis

This is my `data`

```
[1] "the rooms were clean very comfortable and the staff was amazing they went over and beyond to help make our stay enjoyable i highly recommend this hotel for anyone visiting downtown "
[2] "excellent property and very convenient to activities front desk staff is extremely efficient, pleasant and helpful property is clean and has a fantastic old time charm             "                                                                                                                                                                    
[3] "the rooftop cafeteria of hotel was great. wen i say food was great           "
```

I want to create a function that returns the count of positive sentiments per row. This is my code so far.

```
x=data$sentences[1:3]

library(tidytext)
library(tm)

bing <- get_sentiments("bing")
positive = bing %>% filter(sentiment %in% "positive")
positive = subset(positive, select = -c(sentiment))
positive = as.vector(positive$word)
positive = paste0(positive," ")

positive_reviews <- function(x) {
    data = as.vector(x)
    data = Corpus(VectorSource(data))
    data = tm_map(data, removePunctuation)
    data = as.character(data)
        
  positive_count = sapply(positive, function(x) str_count(data,x))
  return(sum(positive_count))
}

print(positive_reviews(x))
```

I am running into an error that I do not know how to fix.

```
Error: no function to return from, jumping to top level
```

How would I write my code to make this work?

Comment: Your `for` loop is not utilising the "i" at all, and are you missing the `{}` that encloses the for loop?

Comment: Hi Edward, thank you. Would you be able to point out where I can use "i" ? I am fairly new to R and would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Hard to tell without some data. Could you please post a small subset of your `data`, or at least the object `x`. A minimal reproducible example is needed. Also, please include all non-standard R libraries that you loaded in your question.

Comment: I edited it now with some data as well as the libraries

Comment: I think all you need to do is remove this line: `for (i in 1:401)` since it is unnecessary. Then, run the function. It works for me. The answer should be 17.

Comment: How can I separate the sum so it shows for each row?